# Azure VM - Block traffic to port if coming from outside the datacenter

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have a group of VM in windows azure that provide a backend service (elasticsearch) to a web application (also hosted on azure).

What we want to do is to block any request to port 9200 that comes from outside the datacenter.

Is it possible in windows azure VMs to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If using IaaS, keep port 9200 on the Vm open just do not create an InputEndpoint for the private port 9200 and traffic will not be allowed from the Internet (through your VIP). To communicate amongst VMs, if your VMs are on the same virtual network, they can talk to each other through the DIP.

Essentially, you are leveraging the VIP as a NAT to prevent requests from the internet from reaching your VM.